# Can't use a string in .m

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, macos

I'm making an app where I have different things: images, videos,a viewController(.h and .m) and another file (let's call it file2, with .h and .m too)

The problem is that I want to use a string from the viewController.h in file2.m, and I can't. I tried this:

```
// ViewController.h

{
  NSString *string;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *string;


//ViewController.m

 @synthesize string;

    // file2.m

#import"viewController.h"

- (IBAction)changestring:(id)sender {
  string = @"something";
}
```

So Xcode returns to me an error when I try to change the string. What am I doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: You need to specify the error XCode is returning in your post.

Comment: Use of undeclarated identifier 'string'

Comment: Please post a correct minimal example. As is that will not compile. Show a simple interface declaration in the header file and the simplest implementation with just the method changeString.

Comment: OK! In a minute I'll change it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a property for your string in viewController.h outside the interface like this

```
viewController.h

{
NSString *string;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *string;
```

and synthesize it in

```
viewController.m

@synthesize string;
```

So that you can access that string in other files where you imported your viewController.h

EDIT:

create an object for your viewController.h in file2 and access like this

```
file2.h
   {
viewController *viewCont;
}
    file2.m

 #import"viewController.h"

-(IBAction)changestring:(id)sender
  {
      viewCont.string=@"something";
}
```

Comment: Use of undeclarated identifier 'string'

Comment: And I have declared it in viewController.h